# Page width blocked at 769px on iPad (landscape orientation)

Tags: ipad, width

I don't understand why the width of [my test web page](http://goo.gl/rGzjSM) is blocked at 769px in landscape orientation (instead of being 1024px) when I view it on my iPad, since nothing in my markup or CSS defines such limit.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: try change viewport to: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: Just changed it, same result. Actually the page width seems to change randomly since right now I have 641px in landscape and 418px in portrait.

Comment: Are you sure? The example doesn't have that tag, and when I've copied your page and changed it locally it is now showing properly on ipad.

Comment: I didn't update the right file, it actually works :) Thanks Marcin !